# Find a group of graphs with coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm trying to find the solution for the following question.

I want to find all graphs with $\mathcal{X}(G) = 3$ where it is possible to delete a vertex and get $\mathcal{X}(G) = 2$

I found out that a cycle is $3$ colorable if the number of vertices is odd and $2$ colorable if the number of vertices is even.

Furthermore I know that every bipartite graph is $2$ colorable.

Is every $3$ colorable graph which turns into a bipartite graph when deleting one vertex the solution I am looking for? Or is the solution not sufficient and misses some graphs?

Answer (score 3):

since the chromatic number is $3$ there must be an odd cycle.

Clearly there can be no vertices outside of this odd cycle because deleting it would not make the graph $2$-colorable. On the other hand there can be no edge that does not belong to the cycle. Notice such an edge would split the original cycles into two smaller cycles, one of these cycles is odd. Taking a vertex outside of this new smaller cycle would yield a contradiction.

We conclude the graph must be an odd cycle.